# How to show error message on forms project when its already catched in library

Tags: vb.net

Have some windows form with nice circural progress bar which i show user during long database function process. There is also task which calls function which inside i got query with transaction and there is catch implemented to rollback if it fails and return either true/false about state of process after finished. I didn't place there memssage box to show error as it's not adviced to store message boxes along in library projects so i would like to show this error on my task level function (in catch). However since i am catching error inside my function i am not able to show it (catch it) on the task's catch. How to accomplish that?

The only idea in my head is to instead of returning only result also return catched error message with use of Tuple like this: Tuple(Of Boolean, String). So i would be able to return two things: result and error message text. I am not so sure if this is right way to do such things. Looking for your advice.

This comes from windows forms project:

```
Dim pic As New CircuralWindowsForms(eCircularProgressType.Donut)
Dim tsk As Task(Of Boolean) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(Function()
Dim resu = False
    Try
         resu = createArticle.ProcessArticle(data)
     Catch sqlex As Exception
         pic.Invoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show(pic, sqlex.Message))
     Finally
         '--Close form once done (on GUI thread)
         pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.Close()))
     End Try
          Return resu
End Function)
'Show circural form
pic.ShowDialog()
Task.WaitAll(tsk)

if tsk.Result = true Then
...
```

This comes from library project:

```
Public Function ProcessArticle(data as Data) As Boolean
       Dim result = false

       Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
           Try
              connection.Open()
              Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
              transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
              .....
              transaction.Commit()
              result=true
            Catch ex As Exception
              result = False
              transaction.Rollback()
            End Try
        End Using

        return result
End Function
```

**Extended question a bit (discussion with sstan):**

```
Public Sub DeleteAllRelated(varId As Integer)
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Dim commit As Boolean = True
            con.Open()
            Dim tran As SqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt = CType(New Variation_VariationAttributeDAL().GetAllByVariationId(varId), DataTable)
            If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    If commit Then commit = commit And New Artikel_VariationDAL().DeleteByVariation_VariationAttribute(CInt(row(0)), tran)
                Next
            End If

            If commit Then commit = commit And New Variation_VariationAttributeDAL().DeleteAllWhereVarId(varId, tran)
            If commit Then commit = commit And Delete(varId, tran)
            If commit Then commit = commit And New DALSubKategorie_Variation().Delete(varId, tran)
            If commit Then
                tran.Commit()
            Else
                tran.Rollback()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

this is e.g for:   If commit Then commit = commit And New DALSubKategorie_Variation().Delete(varId, tran)

```
  Public Function Delete(varId As Integer, Optional transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing) As Boolean
            Dim result As Boolean = False
            If transaction Is Nothing Then
Try
                Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " & SharedData.Write.T(SharedData.Tables.SubKategorie_Variation) & " WHERE FK_Variation_ID=@FK_Variation_ID", con)
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_ID", varId)
                        con.Open()
                        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        con.Close()
                        result = True
                    End Using
                End Using
Catch ex as Exception
Throw
End Try
            Else
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " & SharedData.Write.T(SharedData.Tables.SubKategorie_Variation) & " WHERE FK_Variation_ID=@FK_Variation_ID", transaction.Connection)
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_ID", varId)
                    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    result = True
                End Using
            End If
            Return result
        End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it would be wrong for your library to display message boxes directly. But that doesn't mean it should swallow exceptions either.  In, fact, quite the opposite: you really should let the exception bubble up to the caller, and let the caller decide what to do with it.

With that in mind, I would change the `ProcessArticle` function to the following:

```
Public Sub ProcessArticle(data as Data)
       Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
           Try
              connection.Open()
              Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
              transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
              ' .....
              transaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
              transaction.Rollback()
              Throw 'Rethrow exception. The caller can decide what to do with it.
            End Try
        End Using
End Sub
```

Notice how the exception is still caught to enable the transaction rollback, but the exception is rethrown so that the caller can catch it.  This in turn means that you no longer need to return a boolean to indicate success or failure.

**EDIT**

Not directly related to your question, but I would further move the code around a little bit so that I don't accidentally try to rollback a transaction before it has even begun (With you current code, ask yourself what would happen if an error occurred while trying to open the connection?):

```
Public Sub ProcessArticle(data as Data)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        connection.Open()

        Using transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            Try
                ' do work here

                transaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                transaction.Rollback()
                Throw 'Rethrow exception. The caller can decide what to do with it.
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

More on the [Throw Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx):

> A `Throw` statement with no expression can only be used in a `Catch` statement, in which case the statement rethrows the exception currently being handled by the `Catch` statement.

**EDIT 3**: Simplified version of your last edit

```
Public Sub DeleteAllRelated(varId As Integer)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        con.Open()

        Using transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            Try
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt = CType(New Variation_VariationAttributeDAL().GetAllByVariationId(varId), DataTable)
                If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                        New Artikel_VariationDAL().DeleteByVariation_VariationAttribute(CInt(row(0)), tran)
                    Next
                End If

                New Variation_VariationAttributeDAL().DeleteAllWhereVarId(varId, tran)
                Delete(varId, tran)
                New DALSubKategorie_Variation().Delete(varId, tran)

                'If we made it this far without an exception, then commit.
                tran.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                tran.Rollback()
                Throw 'Rethrow exception.
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


Public Sub Delete(varId As Integer, Optional transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing)
    If transaction Is Nothing Then
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " & SharedData.Write.T(SharedData.Tables.SubKategorie_Variation) & " WHERE FK_Variation_ID=@FK_Variation_ID", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_ID", varId)
                con.Open()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Else
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " & SharedData.Write.T(SharedData.Tables.SubKategorie_Variation) & " WHERE FK_Variation_ID=@FK_Variation_ID", transaction.Connection)
            cmd.Transaction = transaction
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_ID", varId)
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT 4**: Example of exception chaining

```
Public Sub ProcessArticle(data as Data)
    Try
        ' do work here
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' If you want the original error to go up to the "upper levels"
        ' but with additional information, you need to throw a new
        ' instance of an exception with a new message that contains the additional information
        ' but you need to pass the original exception as a parameter to the constructor
        ' so that exceptions get chained together.
        ' If an "upper level" caller catches the chained exception, 
        ' doing "ex.ToString" will provide all the information.
        ' Try it out, see how it works.
        Throw New Exception("put your additional information here", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: that's great ! I see that when i put throw as you did it will redirect to the Catch sqlex As Exception pic.Invoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show(pic, sqlex.Message)) so user can see the message. Is it right way to do in this way and how its possible throw is redirecting error to tasks's catch? And is that Throw's action to always redirect error message to caller? I never used this before.

Comment: I added a little extra info at the end of my post.  But basically, it's called *rethrowing* an exception.  I absolutely think it's a correct practice to rethrow an exception in that way if you know you need to take some action when an exception occurs, but you still want the callers to have a chance to catch and deal with the exception.  I feel that the code becomes so much cleaner as a result.

Comment: so simply saying Throw will redirect  error message to the caller's catch that's the purpose of it? What if caller not have catch?

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the `throw` statement causes the exception to be thrown as if you had never caught it in the first place. If the caller doesn't have a catch, the exception will keep travelling back up the call stack until one of the methods has a catch block somewhere.  But that's just normal exception behavior. Nothing weird about that.

Comment: is it correct to say?: throw will not show error in current catch but will be looking for upper catch (in the caller) - if not in caller it will look more upper until he find catch? Is the purpose to use Throw in such situation that if we want exception to be handled by not current catch but caller's catch/upper level's catchs?

Comment: Sure, but just return a value if you actually have a meaningful value to return.  Returning a true/false to indicate success or failure is not needed.  And if you really think about it, if an exception gets thrown when there is a failure, when would a false value ever be returned? (Hint: never)

Comment: so what you say is even if i set my result value to true in catch of ProcessArticle and when it comes to error (Throw) this value will be not returned right (i mean ProcessArticle will not return any value is it correct ?)

Comment: Correct. No value can be returned if an exception is thrown.

Comment: To get what i mean please look at my main post i added code to get you full picture - is it correct? What i am missing there to be fully ok? I think in case of error it will fail at all or? Thanks if you could take a look. I think i need to add try/catch and Throw in every combined functions and then make one try/catch in DeleteAllRelated so i can rollback and handle error from every combined right or just one try/catch in DeleteAllRelated would be enough? I can make another topic if you like.

Comment: I looked at the code. You're definitely overcomplicating things and the code will not work correctly.  Consider what will happen if a SQL exception is thrown from your `Delete` function... will the caller's `DeleteAllRelated` function call `tansaction.Rollback`?  No, it won't.  That's the weakness of trying to return the status as a boolean.  I think you should play around with the code a little to test these scenarios so that you see what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120189/discussion-between-sstan-and-jimmyjimm).

Comment: so instead of returning boolean - should i just implement try/catch within all combined queries (for each of them) insert Throw, so if error occurs in one of them it will redirect it to the catch of DeleteAllRelated (which i would need to add as well) and there i roollback from this point?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer so that you can see how I would code the `Delete` and `DeleteAllRelated` methods.  As you can see, the code is a lot more straight forward, and will handle errors (rollback the transaction) more correctly than your version.  The fact that the `Delete` function only ever returned `true` should have been a sign that something was not quite right with the design.

Comment: And to your last comment: no.  You don't need a try-catch in every method.  You just need it in the `DeleteAllRelated` method where the transaction handling happens, and so you need to catch the exception to know if you need to rollback.  Not having a try-catch will allow exceptions to work their way up the call stack naturally.  You don't need to code anything special to make that work.

Comment: Like I said, play around with this pattern.  Once you wrap your head around it, I'm sure you'll appreciate it's simplicity and correctness.

Comment: thats very clear to me now - but one more thing as you see in Delete for instance there is also query which is not used with transaction because sometimes i need only one query so i dont combine with others in transaction.so in this case should i implement try/catch (throw) within it? I mean code behind : If transaction Is Nothing Then..

Comment: I don't see why you would need one in that case either. What would you do in the catch block?  Rule of thumb: don't code a try-catch block unless you have something meaningful to do when an exception occurs.  And if you do need one, always make sure to rethrow the exception in the catch block unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: but look if i would call Delete function (not in transaction combined with others like in  function DeleteAllRelated) just Delete directly i dont have there any try/catch so i was thinking to add for this try/catch throw. Only the code block within: If transaction Is Nothing Then..

Comment: But what for?  What would it accomplish?  What would you code in the catch block?

Comment: just Throw. Let's say i am calling it somwhere from my code: Delete(10). Then if error occurs there will be throw in catch which return error message to upper level

Comment: You don't need a try-catch block to accomplish that.  It will just happen automatically.  Test it out.

Comment: i show it now in main post - look please (Delete function) this way when using within transaction as you shown in DeleteAllRelated  will be catched, but when just using somwhere else without transaction i would have Throw to redirect to upper level.

Comment: I saw your edit. But I stand by what I said.  That try/catch doesn't accomplish anything but clutter the code.  The behavior will be identical if you omit it.  Errors will automatically make their way up the call stack to the *upper level*.

Comment: ok so i turn back to beggining so why then we would need Throw in ProcessArticle (early beggining discussion) if it goes automaticly to upper level? Don't get it (amybe i am stupid :( )

Comment: Because in that case, you need to catch the exception to perform the transaction rollback.  But because the catch block prevents the exception from continuing up the call stack, you also need the `Throw` statement to allow the exception to be re-raised after the rollback is performed.  If the rollback was not necessary, then the try-catch would be unnecessary as well.

Comment: ok finally i get it i think with your help :) So answering my own question for non transaction queries like Delete - no need to add additional catch throw as it will goes upper level where i will be ready to catch this right - upper level try/catch to avoid libraries mess..? :)

Comment: Yes! I still think it would be worth it if you took a step back and just played around with exceptions in a little test program, just to get a feel for how they work.  I'm sure that with a little testing around, it will all become much clearer. Good luck

Comment: closing question: is there possible by this Throw function to add additional information somehow inside it not just error message? MANY THANKS & good day or night !

Comment: Yes, you can do that by chaining exceptions.  I'll add one last edit to my answer to show you what that looks like.

Comment: ok thanks man really thanks ! learned a lot out of your posts of course will do some tests as you adviced, there is something to learn...